# Nextjs/React createPortal - Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element | DocumentFragment'

Tags: typescript, next.js, eslint, portal

I am EXTREMELY new to typescript.

I've been creating a project using a lot of pre-configured react components that are Javascript files (.js). I need to convert everything to typescript (.tsx) without it throwing any ESLint errors. Note that I am not able to use the non-null assertion (!) because of how my ESLint is configured.

Right now I'm trying to convert a portal component (createPortal) to typescript and I've been getting a variety of errors depending on the types I specify.

This is my code:

```
import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";
import React from "react";
import { useCallback } from "react";

type ClientOnlyPortalProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  // Is there a type for CSS id?
  selector: string;
};

export default React.memo(function ClientOnlyPortal({
  children,
  selector,
}: ClientOnlyPortalProps) {
  const ref = useRef<Element | DocumentFragment | null>(null);
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                          //1. not sure if this is correct^
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  if (ref == null) {
  }

  useEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      ref.current = document.querySelector(selector);
      setMounted(true); 
       ^^^^
         //2. ref.current has a ts error if I remove null from #1
      console.log("ClientOnlyPortal useEffect fired");
    }, [selector])
  );

  return mounted ? createPortal(children, ref.current) : null;
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
                                     //3. This error is always here
});
```

1. If I remove null from here, then I get an error @ #2.

This is potential error @ #2:

> Cannot assign to 'current' because it is a read-only property.ts(2540)

2. This error is always here:

```
Argument of type 'Element | DocumentFragment | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element | DocumentFragment'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element | DocumentFragment'.ts(2345)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Hoping that by converting all of my javascript components, I become waaaay more competent in typescript. I need a typescript tutor :/

.................................................................

Comment: Update - I was able to remove my errors by doing the following:

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my errors by doing the following. Any constructive criticism?

```
 import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { createPortal } from "react-dom";
    import React from "react";
    import { useCallback } from "react";
    
    type ClientOnlyPortalProps = {
      children: React.ReactNode;
      // Is there a type for CSS id?
      selector: string;
    };
    
    export default React.memo(function ClientOnlyPortal({
      children,
      selector,
    }: ClientOnlyPortalProps) {
      const ref = useRef<Element | DocumentFragment | null>(null);
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                    //added this
      const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
    
      //eslint-disable-next-line
      useEffect(
        useCallback(() => {
          ref.current = document.querySelector(selector);
          setMounted(true);
          console.log("ClientOnlyPortal useEffect fired");
        }, [selector])
      );
    
      if (ref.current == null) {
        return null;
      }
        ^^^^^^^^^^ 
           //Added this

      return mounted ? createPortal(children, ref.current) : null;
    });
```

Note that the 'eslint-disable-next-line' is due to an error that says:

> React Hook useEffect received a function whose dependencies are
> unknown. Pass an inline function instead.